# Convert a plain array with indexed links to a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, tree

I have a problem with a recursion function creation with php language with the next problem:
I have a 1 dimension array that represents a tree, by example the next:

```
$A = array(array(1, "Root", 0), array(2, "Child1", 1), array(3, "Child2", 1), array(4, "Child3", 1), array(5, "Leaf1", 2));
```

This means an simple tree with one root (Root), that has 3 branches with 3 childs (Child1, Child2 and Child2), and from Child1 has a branch to Leaf1. Each element of this array simbolizes the next: first index is the Id, seconds is the the string name, and the 3rd is the link where belongs, excepts 0 that means the root and has no ancestors.
I need a recursive function in php that converts this array to the next:

```
$Tree = array(1, array(2, array(3), 3, 4));
```

I begun to work with the next function:

```
Array2TreeRecursive(array &$tree, int $ident) {}
```

This function is called the first time like as

```
Array2TreeRecursive([], 1) {}
```

Any idea of has to implements this function (we assume we have a function called GetChildren(id), that using an id, returns a simple array with the next childen of the given id, but returns an empty array if it's leaf or a null if the id doesn't exists.

Many thanks,

Dani

Answer (score 0):

the expected output you posted is a little bit confusing.

What you want might be something like this:

```
$A = array(array(1, "Root", 0), array(2, "Child1", 1), array(3, "Child2", 1), array(4, "Child3", 1), array(5, "Leaf1", 2));
$am = new arraymodifier();
$am->source_array = $A;
$B = $am->modify();
echo "<pre>".var_export($B,true)."</pre>";

class arraymodifier {

    public $source_array;    

    function modify($startat=0) {

        $res = array();        
        $childs = $this->getchilds($startat);        
        foreach($childs as $c) {
            $cld = $this->modify($c[0]);
            $res[] = array('item'=>$c,'childs'=>$cld);
        }
        return $res;
    }

    function getchilds($parent) {
        $res = array();
        foreach($this->source_array as $s) {
            if($s[2] == $parent) {
                $res[] = $s;
            }
        }
        return $res;
    }

}
```